# Possible leak of an IOBufferMemoryDescriptor in DriverKit driver

Tags: c++, ios, iokit, ipados, driverkit

I have a DriverKit driver for iPadOS. It works fine, but the static analyzer is flagging a possible leak that I don't understand. The code flagged is in the driver class itself:

```cpp
void IMPL(CDCDriver, ReadComplete)
{
    // Simply trampolines back to USBCDCInterface where the read is actually handled
    IOBufferMemoryDescriptor *readDataBuffer = ivars->cdcInterface->readData(status, actualByteCount, completionTimestamp);
    if (actualByteCount > 0) {
        os_log(OS_LOG_DEFAULT, "[Driver] Got %u bytes of data!", actualByteCount);
        if (ivars->client != nullptr) {
            ivars->client->dataWasReceived(readDataBuffer, actualByteCount);
        }
    }
}  // [!] Potential leak of an object stored into 'readDataBuffer'
```

[image: Screenshot of static analyzer results]

According to the analyzer, the call to `readData()` on the first line of the method returns an `OSObject` of type `IOBufferMemoryDescriptor` with a +1 retain count. However, that method is implemented like so:

```cpp
IOBufferMemoryDescriptor *USBCDCInterface::readData(IOReturn status,
                                                    uint32_t actualByteCount,
                                                    uint64_t completionTimestamp)
{
    pollForData();
    return readDataBuffer;
}
```

Here, `readDataBuffer` is a member variable of `USBCDCInterface`, created when the driver is started with a call to `IOUSBHostInterface::CreateIOBuffer()`:

```cpp
IOBufferMemoryDescriptor *readDataBuffer = nullptr;
result = dataInterface->CreateIOBuffer(kIOMemoryDirectionIn, 256, &readDataBuffer);
if (result != kIOReturnSuccess) {
    return result;
}
this->readDataBuffer = readDataBuffer;
```

My understanding of `OSObject` (and subclasses there of) is that it uses a reference counting mechanic very similar to `NSObject`. Creating it, e.g. with `CreateIOBuffer()` should result in an object with a +1 retain count. The `USBCDCInterface` instance that created it owns it, and therefore should `release()` it when it's done with it (in `USBCDCInterface::free()`). Simply returning it from `readData()` shouldn't transfer ownership, and it shouldn't be the responsibility of the caller of that method to release it. Notably, calling `release()` on the object at the end of `CDCDriver::ReadComplete()` causes the driver to crash, just as I'd expect, which makes me think it's a false positive from the analyzer.

Either my understanding is flawed, and there's something about returning that object from `USBCDCInterface::readData()` that (by convention or otherwise) obligates the caller to release it (again though, doing so crashes the driver), or else this is a false positive on the part of the analyzer.

If this were ObjC/Cocoa, I'd guess that there's something about the naming of my methods causing the analyzer to assume the `readData()` method effectively transfers ownership (like a `-copy` or `+alloc` method), but I can't find any documentation of naming conventions like that, nor have I been able to work out if/how `OSObject` methods are annotated with their memory management semantics.

Can anyone provide any insight?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should have continued the “if this were Objective-C/Cocoa” thought to its logical conclusion: `OSObject` refcounting [follows <s>the same</s> a similar convention](https://github.com/apple-oss-distributions/xnu/blob/1031c584a5e37aff177559b9f69dbd3c8c3fd30a/iokit/DriverKit/OSObject.iig#L147) as Objective-C and CoreFoundation's. You have 2 options:

- Rename your function to follow convention; so for example, change it to `GetReadData()`. The vast majority of Apple's own DriverKit APIs follow the convention.
- Annotate it. The annotation to use in your case should I believe be [`DRIVERKIT_RETURNS_NOT_RETAINED`](https://github.com/apple-oss-distributions/xnu/blob/1031c584a5e37aff177559b9f69dbd3c8c3fd30a/iokit/DriverKit/OSObject.iig#L171) which should normally evaluate to [`__attribute__((os_returns_not_retained))`](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/AttributeReference.html#os-returns-not-retained).

Comment: Thank you! Note though that this is not the same convention as Objective-C/CF. In those, functions/methods are assumed to return an object with a +0 retain count unless they're prefixed with alloc/init, new, copy, or mutableCopy. So kind of the inverse. But that's the exact documentation I was looking for and couldn't find. Working fine now!

Comment: @AndrewMadsen Ah yes, you're right of course. There's no concept of autorelease semantics in OSObject/C++, so the only time anything can be returned with +0 retain count is when the original owner stays the owner, i.e. essentially a getter.